# Running in the Terminal a build made in XCode, how?

Tags: c++, xcode, ide, opencv

Im creating a project in Xcode using OpenCV as a framework. It works great with the Build&Run option from Xcode, but now I need to run it in the Terminal and it gives me this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/OpenCV.framework/Versions/A/OpenCV
Referenced from: /Users/Victor/Documents/PFC/src/opencv/blob/build/Release/./test3
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

I look for the build and just execute it with ./

So, any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run it from the build directory rather than the Release directory (assuming Frameworks is a directory in blob)

Comment: In the build folder there are just the more folders: Debug, Release and blob.build. blob.build, which would be the best candidate, has another two folder: Debug and blob.pbxindex

Comment: ok, I was building it in debug mode, so that means i was sort of an idiot... I buildt it as a release and now I can run the object under Build/Release :)

Thanks for you answers!